# React useEffect and Axios: Making chained API calls within 'then'

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm working with the NHL API and retrieving hockey stats for my app. The API has multiple endpoints that I'm using to access player stats.

`Roster endpoint`

https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/3/roster

After I retrieve this data I can access an object called `person` which contains an ID number for that individual player's API endpoint that contains pedigree information (i.e. country they are from, height/weight, etc..). I can then send an API request that looks like this to retrieve more data for that individual player, in this case `8476191` is the ID number.

`Pedigree Info endpoint:`

https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8476191

I can also pass the ID number, `8476191`, to a stats endpoint which contains stats for the same player.

`Stats endpoint:`

https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8476191/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20182019

What I would like to do is send a request to the `Roster endpoint`, grab the ID numbers for every player on the roster, and then make subsequent API calls to the `Pedigree info endpoint` and the `stats endpoint` using the ID number.

How can I make an `Axios` get request to the roster endpoint and then nest two more get requests within the call that can access the ID number from the first call? Here is what I attempted:

```
// State for retrieving player ID numbers from roster endpoint
const [playerIDNumbers, setPlayerIDNumbers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    // Get the roster data, set playerIdNumbers to an array containing all the ID numbers
   axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${teams[teamName].id}/roster`)
       .then(res => {
           setPlayerIDNumbers(Object.values(res.data.roster).map((x) => {
               return x.person.id;
           }));
           // res now contains all the ID numbers
           console.log(res);
       })
       // After grabbing all the ID numbers for each player on the roster, I want to map through each ID 
       // in the array and send a request for each player's pedigree data
       .then(res => {
           // Later in my code I created an array to contain the IDs called playerIDArr
           playerIDArr.map((playerID) => {
               axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${playerID}/`)
           })
           console.log('Player ID call returned : ' + res);
       })
       // After this is done I want to make a third request using the ID numbers to grab the stats /////from the stats endpoint
       /* Stats Axios request would go here */
       .catch(err => {
           console.log('Error : ' + err);
       })
}, [])
```

Comment: Not sure why you set player id numbers in state, you can return the numbers and do a Promise.all with the ids in the next `.then`. You currently try to use the [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) of playerIDArr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to keep the state, here is how to do this using a closure:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${teams[teamName].id}/roster`)
    // get all ids
    .then(res => Object.values(res.data.roster).map((x) => x.person.id))
    // map through ids and retrieve the data 
    .then(ids => {
      const people = Promise.all(ids.map(id => axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${id}/`)))

      const stats = Promise.all(ids.map(id => axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/stats/${id}/`)))

      return Promise.all([people, stats])

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error : ' + err);
    })
})

// or using async/await, and some refactoring

const getRoster = id => axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/${id}/roster`)

const getPerson = id => axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${id}/`)

const getStats = id => axios.get(`https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/stats/${id}/`)

useEffect(() => {
  const res = await getRoster(teams[teamName].id)
  const ids = Object.values(res.data.roster).map(x => x.person.id)
  return Promise.all(ids.map(id => Promise.all([getPerson(id), getStats(id)])))
})
```

Comment: Both versions will work but will package the results differently. To be equivalent to the first version, the second would need to be 
`return Promise.all([
 Promise.all(ids.map(getPerson)),
 Promise.all(ids.map(getStats))
])` (at least I think so).